# Is there a way to put a ToolTip onto specific text?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to put a ToolTip on specific text with C#. I have been unable to do this. My following code is as follows:

Matches:

```cs
    string errors = @"SendLuaScript|SendCSharpScript|SendRubyScript";
                MatchCollection errorsMatches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, errors);
```

Set properties for these matches:

```cs
foreach (Match m in errorsMatches)
            {
                ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGray;
                tip.IsBalloon = true;
                tip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                tip.SetToolTip(richTextBox1, "ERROR. You must use void SendLuaScript.");

            }
```

However,  I know this sets a ToolTip for the entire RichTextBox, but I want it to be just specific text.

Comment: You could use the MousEMove event to find the text under the cursor and test if you want to show a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by TaW, here's some crude starter code to display a tooltip when over your desired text in the richtextbox:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool toolTip = false;
    Point pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    int index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pt);
    string errors = @"SendLuaScript|SendCSharpScript|SendRubyScript";
    MatchCollection errorsMatches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, errors);
    foreach (Match m in errorsMatches)
    {
        if (index >= m.Index && index < m.Index + m.Length)
        {
            toolTip1.Show(m.Value, richTextBox1, pt);
            toolTip = true;
            break;
        }                
    }
    if (!toolTip)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(richTextBox1);
    }
}
```